# 000webhost download button downloads wrong file

Tags: html, download

I am working on creating a website with 000webhost.com. I made it entirely with HTML and CSS. I have a problem. If I run my website by simply opening the index.html file from my computer, he does it perfectly. the download button works whatsoever. but if I 'm going to hightechprogramming15.netne.net and I click on the download button, it downloads a different file called download.htm. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HighTechProgramming15</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>HighTechProgramming15</h1>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="nav">
                <h3>Navigation</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="selected" href="Page2.html">Downloads</a></li>
                    <br />
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCz6Obm2NLxc9w-jCb3l8H3w">Link to my YouTube channel</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <h2>Downloads Page</h2>
                <a href="MessageBox Generator.exe" class="button">MessageBox Generator</a>
                <br />

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Copyright &copy; 2016 HighTechProgramming15
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: OK, let's get serious... The two obvious issues here are 1. the string `MessageBox Generator.exe` is _not_ a valid URL, the blank character in there would have to be URL encoded ("percent encoded, so `MessageBox%20Generator.exe`). 2. the name a browser uses to save some payload it downloads from a http server mostly depends on the http headers sent by the server. So the additional meta information provided to the browser. So you will have to dig into what headers _are_ actually sent by that server. We cannot tell you, only you can.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem i think you'll have to put MessageBox%20Generator.exe in place for MessageBox Generator.exe and Maybe you'll have to put download attribute i

Comment: i already tried that but then i will automaticly to http://error404.000webhost.com/?

Comment: Maybe make MessageBox_Generator.exe is safer than with %20 and make .<a href="MessageBox_Generator" download>Download</a>. but make sure you dont make mistakes with the MessageBox Generator name @HighTechProgramming15

Comment: I dont need help anymore with this. I am now working with PHP ;)

Comment: OK nice you'll have a lot more functions in php